# Environment variables sometimes don't update and sometimes aren't accurate

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt - some wonky stuff seems to happen with environment variables within Heroku that doesn't happen at all in my local dev environment. At the moment, I'm trying to troubleshoot why

```
let url = process.env.API_URL + 'me?api_token=' + this.$route.query.api_token;
```

produces the following URL which of course is throwing an error:

```
https://pros.global/api/v1/undefinedme?api_token=test'
```

It clearly appears to be grabbing the correct API_URL from my environment variables (`https://pros.global/api/v1`), but it's as if there is something in between the `API_URL` and the `me` that is undefined.

To make matters worse, it's almost impossible to simply change an environment variable and see it reflected on the frontend. I've tried restarting the heroku dyno as well as doing a refresh deploy, which does a fresh `npm run build` and `npm start`.

The code that runs server side within `asyncData()` appears to reflect the change immediately but client-side code doesn't seem to refresh for 5 to 10 minutes if at all. I'm trying to simply sanity check that the values in the config are being pulled through.

I've tried hard refreshing with `Update on reload` set for the service worker and I've also tried manually unregistering the service worker.

Comment: How about a `console.log(process.env.API_URL)` right before your let statement just to make sure it has what you expect?

Comment: @davejagoda it shows undefined when I log it

Comment: Meaning it shows this: `https://pros.global/api/v1/undefined`? When you run locally, are you using `heroku local` to run it? If not, that might be worth a try to see if the behavior happens then.